# use setMaxResults for first table with one to many join native query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-onetomany, nativequery

I'm new to hibernate.
I have a query like following

```
select a.*, b.* from tableA a 
join tableB b on b.aId = a.id 
left join tableC c where <condition>
```

Here relation from a to b is one to many and b to c is one to one.

Now I need to get first number of rows from `tableA` with all the joining results.

For example there are 10 rows in `tableA` each of which are be joining with 2 rows from `tableB`. Now if I'm querying for first 5 rows from `tableA`, then I need all those rows from joining other tables, thats a total of 20 rows.

How do I write native query for this. I need to do a native query I need performance in this case since our query may qualify a huge number rows.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use subquery and `LIMIT`:

```
select a.*, b.* 
from (SELECT * FROM tableA ORDER BY some_col LIMIT 5) a 
join tableB b on b.aId = a.id 
left join tableC c where <condition>
```